# Cron Not Running Tasks Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've searched everywhere and spent hours trying various solutions, but nothing seems to work... As the title explains, cron simply won't execute commands on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

My `/etc/crontab` file looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
*/1 *     * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

My test script is a simple echo 'Hello world' script (named `echo`), which is contained within `/etc/cron.hourly`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Hello world'
```

Calling `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` from any directory prints 'Hello world' to the console as expected, but the task never seems to be executed by cron. I also have a script that automatically backs up a MySQL database in `cron.hourly`. This also executes and produces the expected file when calling `run parts`, so it isn't just an issue of cron not showing `echo` calls. Cron is clearly doing something, however, as I get the following output in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
...
Mar 25 03:05:01 ip-172-31-32-110 CRON[10077]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 25 03:06:01 ip-172-31-32-110 CRON[10108]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 25 03:07:01 ip-172-31-32-110 CRON[10122]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 25 03:08:01 ip-172-31-32-110 CRON[10149]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 25 03:09:01 ip-172-31-32-110 CRON[10162]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Some other things I have tried:

- `sudo crontab -e` and creating a new cron command there (this produces same output in `/var/log/syslog` that `/etc/crontab` does)
- using `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh/`
- `sudo service cron restart`
- Made sure an empty line exists at the bottom of `crontab`
- `sudo chmod 755 echo` to ensure the file is executable

This has been giving me a huge headache, so I'd greatly appreciate any help on the matter!

Comment: This question is more suitable for [ubuntu.se] than here, as it is not programming related. You can find more information about what is appropriate to ask here in the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I feel silly for not having tried this prior to posting. Using `crontab -e` (without `sudo`) and placing the command there solved the issue.

I'd still appreciate if anybody could explain the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this still seems to be an issue in 18.04 LTS.

In my case (and probably others), I found the problem.  `/etc/crontab` has this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Well, if you look for `run-parts` on the system, it's in /bin.  I changed the `PATH` to:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
```